# How to install Wireless Toolkit on Mac?

Tags: macos, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

How would I install [Wireless Toolkit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137162.html) on Mac? Is there any way?

If not, then how would I develop J2ME application on the Mac? I have Eclipse but still need Wireless Toolkit for emulator

Comment: seriously i was expecting some kind of answer... please suggest something....

Comment: WTK was designed only for Windows development. There was good step-by-step article that I bookmarked some time ago to try out, however seems that since then page was closed. There is a similar at http://sarwiki.informatik.hu-berlin.de/Setting_up_the_development_environment you can try and see if it will work for you

Comment: ok thanx for reply... clear my doubt... i'll figure something else